# How to control place of div and svg

Tags: html, css, svg

```css
div {
     text-align:justify;
     color: white;
     font-size:14px;
     font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
     border-style: solid;
     border-color:red;
     height:60px;
     width:230px;
     display:inline-block;
     margin-top:10px;
     margin-left:10px;
     padding-top:0px;
     }
```

```html
<svg height="50" width="200">
  <line x1="50" y1="20" x2="200" y2="20" style="stroke:rgb(255,255,255);stroke-width:2.5"/>
</svg>
<div>Modern architecture first took off in Europe and then made its way into the American style.</div>
```

I have a problem with SVG and div. I have div (box with some text) next to the SVG line.
The problem is that when I add div, the SVG line from the top will go to the place in the center of div.
I want SVG exactly at the bottom of capital A in the word Architecture.
help!

Comment: Please add the code snippet including html and css

Comment: May I ask why? What id the final goal? Because if you want want to decorate the `A` letter with underline, you have better options..